# How do I handle multiple values from a single select field in Sinatra?

Tags: html, ruby, select, post, sinatra

I have an HTML form with a  element in a page that part of a Sinatra app, e.g.

```
<form action="/form" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" id="text">
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="select">Selection</label>
    <select name="select" id="select">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    <label for="multi_select" multiple>MultipleSelection</label>
    <select name="multi_select" id="multi_select" multiple>
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

If the user selects A & C from the multi_select, the POST handler in Sinatra is supposed to return the selected values, but because `params` is a hash, it only returns the last selected value (so `params[:multi_select]` = "C").

For various reasons, I can't use Javascript or other front-end tricks to change how the value is sent. Is there a good way to handle this correctly server-side? I haven't worked much with Sinatra prior to this project.

Comment: [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinatrarb/qA8tNbtMApE) implies that if you format the name like an array it will work. Have you tried `<select name="multi_select[]"...`

Comment: D'oh! Yes, that solves it. If you'd like to move the comment to a response. I'd be happy to flag that as the right answer. Also, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinatrarb/qA8tNbtMApE) implies that the name of the multiselect needs to look like an array for Sinatra to pick up all the values. Try changing it to:

```
<select name="multi_select[]" id="multi_select" multiple>
```